# SAML 2.0 Unable to see X509Certificate value in SAML assertion

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, opensaml

I have Jks and *.cer files loded in saml configurations correctly but generated saml assertion unable to locate certificate tags like , , inside signature...what could be the reason I have Keyinfo object correct ly configured

KeyInfo keyInfo = (KeyInfo)create(KeyInfo.class, KeyInfo.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#_27ffd2e4ee3090abd76890d5436b2f62"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="xs" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>iCKAJTHHj1GGfZi6oIIBabGSl2c=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>09n/W4DWmgdvaRF6X88A7Mn7SiYPLB/pWL8rC6GuwqTGhGtHLkljahzVTYATdY84zglyrIoX+ANrIgdz9ITkdZIanm1bI5VgploBcEzjDufEJDQm7DbEPZtBp/PkTLalV+h17D2c3TBGxht1fsJ9IrHFZyNOoukBareyAZwjPLE=</ds:SignatureValue></ds:Signature>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the generate function of BasicKeyInfoGeneratorFactory.BasicKeyInfoGenerator

If you send in you credential, you get a keyinfo object back.

Then use setKeyInfo on your signature to add the information

Answer (score 0):

> Hey Thanks Stefan  Following I have missing and after adding same it
>   find working missed to add publicKey...

```
KeyInfoHelper.addPublicKey(keyInfo, signingCredential.getPublicKey());
      signature.setKeyInfo(keyInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please enable the verbose logging in your `web.config`. Surely you would be able to catch the exact reason for the exception.

Normally its due to  "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic" issue.